# iOS 8 - Starling context loss on open camera roll gallery

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, ios8, flash-builder

I am creating an app on iOS in Flash Builder, with as3.
The app uses the Starling plugin: http://wiki.starling-framework.org/start

My app allows users to take photos and customise them. When attempting to access the camera or camera roll on iOS 8, I get the error message "The application lost the device context!".

On Android, I can get around this problem with this line:

```
            Starling.handleLostContext = true;
```

But I am told that iOS should never lose context (and I haven't seen it lose context on iOS 7 or below).

If I include that line in iOS 8, the application crashes at around the same point, but in this case the app crashes completely, and returns me to the home screen rather than displaying the previous message.

I have heard there are restrictions on iOS 8 with regards to the use of 64 bit/32 bit plugins and extensions, but I am not using any ANEs in this particular app. Are there any other areas where 32-bit could be causing problems or is that strictly related to ANEs?

I don't get this error on iOS 7 or below or Android, unless I set handleLostContext to false.

Adobe Scout provides no error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
This code calls in the camera functionality:

```
var cameraRoll:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll(); 
if(CameraRoll.supportsBrowseForImage) {
    trace("camera rolling");
    cameraRoll.addEventListener(MediaEvent.SELECT, imageSelected); 
    cameraRoll.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.CANCEL, browseCanceled); 
    cameraRoll.addEventListener(flash.events.ErrorEvent.ERROR, galleryMediaError);
    cameraRoll.browseForImage();
} else { 
    var alert:Alert = Alert.show("Image browsing is not supported on this device.", "Error", new ListCollection([{label:"OK"}]));   
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I've switched from AIR SDK 17 to 16, and it is now more stable but has similar issues

Comment: How you take pictures? Unfortunately there's a huge black hole right where AIR works, so you simply don't understand what's going on, why context is lost and why it crashes. Google Play provides at least some crash reports, but with iOS.. I can only pray for your soul :) Good question though, would love to see some feedback!

Comment: It would be easy to put a test case together, request a Context3D then open the cameraroll and see what happens. If it crashes then ios8+/AIR 18 have some problem (your at least using AIR 17 of course) if not then starling needs a update.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with the camera roll in iOS which will cause stage3d to lose context. Your options:

1. Set Starling.handleLostContext = true, it is possible to lose context in iOS.
2. Find an ANE (Supposedly these exist) that handles the camera roll without losing context.

More Information:
http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/starling-and-cameraui#post-77339

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm on ios 8.3 a Context3D is not lost when opening the CameraRoll using AIR 18.

1. Make sure you are using AIR 18.
2. Make sure you are using the latest Starling Version.

If the problem persist it's likely Starling is the cause.

1. Either report the problem and wait for an update.
2. Do not use Starling when requesting the CameraRoll (turn Starling off and Display normal Bitmaps).
3. Don't use Starling and use another engine or create your own.